# Conditional Text Fields Inside Repeating Sections - how to limit lookup scope?

Tags: 2010, infopath

So, here's my challenge: I'm building a tool in SP to help my department track and evaluate new product ideas. I've taken the business architecture/capabilities map and converted it into a series of lists in SP ([level1, level2, etc), which are linked via data connections to the InfoPath form illustrated below. I've created a repeating section that allows end users to drill down into business capabilities and see the resulting maturity and differentiation within the company, as well as take notes on how the product is positioned with respect to the capabilities.

The drop down lists filter based on the prior selection, so Level 5 options are determined by Level 4, etc. Likewise, the fields for maturity and differentiation are automatically populated from the data connection.

[image: Overview of Repeating Section]

The section works fine when it's first filled out, however, the conditional fields (Maturity and Differentiation) don't populate independently. That is, when the section is repeated, the most recent selection in the capabilities column determine the Maturity and Differentiation values throughout ALL repeated sections.

How can I restrict the scope of the conditional reference in this type of repeating section so that my conditional fields are only targeting inside their specific instance?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved!

For those who are interested, here's some more detail on the issue. When repeated, the section exhibited this behavior:

[image]

I looked a little closer into the behavior of the individual text fields and noticed that the fields populated from selections below Level 3 behaved properly. It turned out that the default value lookup for these fields was looking first at the data connection, then at the local field, which prevented InfoPath from updating the XPath property with the current() tag. I updated the filter rules and everything works perfectly now!